# Access array after filter is applied

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to create a function to print all my data from my filtered table.

The problem i have is accessing my array after all filters are applied.
My function in tasks.ts goes out of scope from my class which makes my "this" property undefined in my class.
Is there a better way to achive this?

My custom filter

```
export class PrintValueConverter {
    toView(array, printFunc) {
        printFunc(array);
        return array;
    }
}
```

My Table (tasks.html)

```
<tr virtual-repeat.for="item of tasks | status:statusFilterValue  | print:printFunc"/>
```

My view class (tasks.ts)

```
@autoinject()
export class Tasks {

@bindable statusFilterValue;

tasks: Task[]
filteredTasks: Task[]


printFunc(tasks){
        console.log(tasks);
        console.log(this)
        this.filteredTasks = tasks
    }

}
```

Tasks prints out successfully with my array but this resolves to undefined, why? And how do i achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're calling a function from outside of the scope of the view-model. This means the scope of the function then technically becomes the window scope (presumably).

The point of a value converter is to take a value and convert it. Whether that be a value from an input field or value from a variable in a repeater (like your use-case). The context shouldn't matter because you're dealing with values, not the view-model.

While I think you're using value converters incorrectly, there is a way you can make this work. I recommend you look into better ways of doing what you're trying to achieve.

The simplest solution here would be to pass the context of your view-model through to the value converter as another argument, in this case, it'll be a reference to the view-model class.

```
export class PrintValueConverter {
    toView(array, printFunc, context) {
        printFunc(array, context);
        return array;
    }
}
```

**Then your printFunc would look like this:**

```
printFunc(tasks, context) {
    context.filteredTasks = tasks
}
```

**You will then want to create the reference to `this` available in the view. We'll call this `context`.**

```
constructor() {
    this.context = this;
}
```

**Lastly you will then reference it like this:**

```
<tr virtual-repeat.for="item of tasks | status:statusFilterValue  | print:printFunc:context">
```

This works because Javascript treats all assignments by reference. Meaning if you pass in a reference to your view-model, that same instance will be seen by any other function or part of your application referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can force the scope of your printFunc to the ViewModel's scope by using an arrow function, like so:

```
@autoinject()
export class Tasks {

    @bindable statusFilterValue;

    tasks: Task[]
    filteredTasks: Task[]


    printFunc = (tasks) => {
        console.log(tasks);
        console.log(this)
        this.filteredTasks = tasks
    }

}
```

Then `this` within `printFunc` will always refer to the instance of your `Tasks` class, regardless of where you call it from. So everything else could stay the same.